# determine if any code is running in .net app - For "heartbeat" monitor

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, winapi

I have a Windows Service written in VB.net app that generates documents using Word ( I know already that this is bad idea, but I'm stuck with this for the time being).  Once in a while the app will get hung up on a Word / DCOM issue and stop processing.

Is there a way I can determine if any code is running in my service.  I tried to check the status of the service, but that seems to only indicate if the Service is up and running, not if the service is hung up and not really doing anything.

Is there anything in the Windows API I can use to determine if the service is actually processing anything or not?

Comment: That can be done in your original service with a timeout. If a thread is still executing after a specific time then kill it.

Comment: Not really. Your service should just start another thread that opens a local socket (like an HTTP status page on `127.0.0.1`) that lets you monitor it.

Comment: No, because even a hung application is still running.  It's just hung from your perspective.  It doesn't mean the processor isn't processing anything.

Comment: @the_lotus: How do you propose to kill a thread, and do it safely?

Comment: Automating Office programs from a service is explicitly not supported. You should find a different solution.

Comment: A low tech way would be to have your service write a file to a specific location that you can then periodically check.

Comment: Can you add some code? Also, you mention a Word/DCOM issue. Is that a general complaint about black box voodoo, or is there a specific error that is cropping up?

Comment: [*"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any \[...\] non-interactive client application \[...\], because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) The link includes numerous alternatives, that can be used to implement a reliable solution. Your approach cannot be made reliable.